# Decrypting base64 file causes high memory heap by using crypto-js

Tags: react-native, encryption, cryptojs

I was decrypting a pdf file (about 18mb) in a react native app as following script. 
The input data was an encrypted base64 data.
However the process caused 1.4 ~ 1.8 gb memory usage and make the app crash. 
Is there any bug? Or it just exceeded the limit a cell phone can handle?

> ```
> const bufferData = Buffer.from(encryptedBase64Data, 'base64');
> function decryptDocumentData({ iv, key, data }) {   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>     try {
>
>   const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
>     {
>       ciphertext: CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(data),
>     },
>     CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key.toString('hex')),
>     {
>       iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv.toString('hex')),
>       mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
>       padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
>     }
>   ).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
>
>   resolve(decrypted);
>     } catch (err) {
>       reject(err);
>     }   }); }
> ```

"react-native": "0.59.9",
"react-native-crypto": "^2.2.0",
"rn-fetch-blob": "0.10.15",

Comment: Sorry, I delete resolve by accident. Thank you very much.

Comment: The PDF is too big for your crypto library as it requires the entire file to be in memory before decrypting. Use a crypto library that has a streaming interface, like [asmcrypto](https://github.com/asmcrypto/asmcrypto.js). I cannot vouch for the quality of any Javascript library, however. I find them all disappointing, either because they're missing critical features, and/or because they have atrocious or nonexistent documentation.